# App crashes when list item is clicked

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview

Here, I'm trying to launch a new activity called Detail.class.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, Detail.class);
courseList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

This is all in the onCreate().

It crashes when trying to start the new activity. Help is appreciated.

Comment: can you post error logs please?

Comment: Usually when this happens to me it's because I forgot to put the activity to-be-called in my manifest.  You didn't show the crash error though so this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the manifest file to double cross that "Detail" activity has been declared or not..and ya kindly post the logcat to recognize the cause of crash